# CMake having multiple executables throws me an error

Tags: cmake

I'm having some trouble with cmake: I'm using cmake for my school project and there is a bonus part but we have to compile another executable for the bonus part, and I tried this:

```c
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(philosophers)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -Werror")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-lpthread")

set(LIBFT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libft42/libft.a)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${LIBFT}
                    COMMAND make
                    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libft42)

link_libraries(philo_bonus ${LIBFT})
link_libraries(philo ${LIBFT})
aux_source_directory(src SRC)
aux_source_directory(src_bonus SRC_BONUS)

add_executable(philo ${SRC} ${LIBFT})
add_executable(philo_bonus ${SRC_BONUS} ${LIBFT})
target_include_directories(philo
                            PUBLIC inc
                            PUBLIC lib/libft42/inc)
target_include_directories(philo_bonus
                            PUBLIC inc_bonus
                            PUBLIC lib/libft42/inc)
```

I removed include_directories and replaced it with target_include_directories because I want my two projects to have separate includes, but when I try to `cmake -Bbuild -H.`, it says:

```c
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (add_executable):
  Target "philo_bonus" links to itself.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (add_executable):
  Target "philo" links to itself.


CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "philo_bonus".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: philo_bonus
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

I don't understand what happened here, I changed nothing in add_executable and it worked fine before I added another.

Comment: You use [link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_libraries.html) command which treats **all its arguments** as libraries to be linked with all following executables/libraries. Probably, you intended to use [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) instead: it links executable/library, specified as the first argument, with all libraries, specified in the rest arguments. In that case you need to place the call to `target_link_libraries` after corresponded `add_executable`.

Comment: Thanks, that was kind of my mistake i want this library to link with both executables, so instead I just needed to do `link_libraries(${LIBFT})` before `add_executable`s and I don't know why I wrote the executables names inside `link_libraries`

Comment: could somebody please write up the answer?